# How do i color my hyperlink text blue in the latex code (Overleaf)?

Tags: hyperlink, latex

Been trying to color this hyperlink the color blue in the latex code:

\pt \href{www.google.com}{My text}\

Tried all the methods listed on online forums but couldn't really find the one which was helpful. Documentation wasn't also that great

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we can see which hyperref options you use etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the color in package options or for single hyperlink. Here both options

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        urlcolor  = blue]{hyperref}
        
\begin{document}


\href{https://www.google.com/}{google}

\href{https://www.google.com/}{\color{red}google}

\end{document}
```